# Docker build timeouts on AWS Beanstalk for Python app

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, firebase-admin

I have a Python2/Django application running on AWS Beanstalk. I use Dockerfile for deployment. Everything was working fine until I added `firebase-admin==3.2.1` dependency to my `requirements.txt`. What happens is that the Docker image build time took longer than usual and Beanstalk build process started to fail. With more analysis, I noticed that a sub-dependency is what takes long time to install, `grpcio==1.31.0`. It is used by Firebase lib to communicate with Google APIs.

I tried to increase the **Command Timeout** setting to 20 min and more but nothing changed. EB deployment process consumes the whole time interval and eventually fails. I tried to get into the EC2 instance itself to find anything useful that I can tweak but found nothing.

This is a sample of the `eb-engine.log` that, I believe, explains the error part.

```
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/6f/8e/a7/c5ce8f1742b7d2b9e07cd1064cf201293d157c3c4e1021a74a
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psutil: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psutil: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/39/a0/f5/c4fa280463e29aea07797acb5312358fefb067c1f4f98e11b1
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Pyphen: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Pyphen: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/78/e3/76/42853bf2f7573a72fb5fe377a8406c979a5479ad6930506cde
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cairocffi: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cairocffi: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/3a/2e/92/89e9dcce600a1a78bebe571fdd096669cba354b29c5e1140b9
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for CairoSVG: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for CairoSVG: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b0/f0/12/0c41649d33dbc95ce0188188feefc8f90aa877363322fd3ace
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gevent: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gevent: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/66/89/6a/7438b05445edc27023a9d8935801d4e70ed962e02541e57fbd
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for httplib2: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for httplib2: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/9a/a8/c3/72684de9397a5633e21ba89911174fbc9eb0b1fb9005c6eaf0
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for grpcio: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for grpcio: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for grpcio: still running...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for grpcio: still running...

2020/11/05 16:12:14.123278 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to build docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/ failed with error Command timed out after 300 seconds 

2020/11/05 16:12:14.123302 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2020/11/05 16:12:14.131856 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to build the Docker image. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1604592734,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1604592734,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2020/11/05 16:12:14.133315 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy
```

As you will notice in the previous sample that the Docker build process fails after exactly 300 seconds regardless of the **Command Timeout** setting value.

```
Stop running the command. Error: failed to build docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker build -t aws_beanstalk/staging-app /var/app/staging/ failed with error Command timed out after 300 seconds
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I found solutions like this (https://serverfault.com/questions/561901/how-to-increase-the-timeout-of-elastic-beanstalk-deployments), but they somehow did not apply to the docker command. It kept failing after 300 seconds.